# Fedora slow login using ssh or telnet using ipaddress

Tags: login, slow-connection

HEllo my friends...

My fedora 7 server has become very slow in the login phase from ssh or telnet.
I just use ip to connect (no dns needs) and when I log locally it's fast as usual.
If I ping or traceroute the server the connection is fast as usual and I get no dropped packets...

Any hints to resolve/debug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be related to DNS?

Try adding this option to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
UseDNS no
```

And then restart your ssh daemon, this should sort it out

Comment: Just tried... No luck :/

Comment: Also tried:

GSSAPIAuthentication no
...to /etc/ssh/ssh_config

No luck

Answer (score 2):

Value no for verifyreversemapping did the trick!

Thanks to lynxman and upvoting for pointing me to the solution